# Reactjs Tab Component

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react.js

I made a simple bare bones Tab component, i'm a beginner when it comes to ReactJS so any advice regarding the codes functionality is greatly appreciated.

## Tab.js Component

```
import React from 'react';

class Tabs extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            activeIndex : 0
        }
    }

    handleOnClick(key, event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            activeIndex : key
        });
    }

    renderNavItem(key) {

        let tab = this.props.children[key];

        return (
            <li key={ key } className={ this.state.activeIndex == key ? 'active' : ''}>
                <a href="#" onClick={ this.handleOnClick.bind(this, key) }>{ tab.props.title }</a>
            </li>
        );
    }

    render() {

        let index = 0;
        let active = this.state.activeIndex;

        let tabs = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                active : child.props.active === true ? true : (active == index++)
            });
        });

        return (
            <div className={ this.props.className }>
                <ul className="tabs-nav">
                    { Object.keys(this.props.children).map(this.renderNavItem.bind(this)) }
                </ul>
                <div className="tabs-content">
                    { tabs }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Tab extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className={ "tab-panel" + (this.props.active ? ' active' : '') }>
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Tab.defaultProps = { 
    active : false 
};

export default {
  Tabs,
  Tab
};
```

## Usage

```
import React from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from './Tabs';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (      
            <Tabs className="tabs-wrapper">
                <Tab active="true" title="Tab One">Tab One content</Tab>
                <Tab title="Tab Two">
                    <div>Tab Two Content</div>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>       
        );
    }
}

React.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

## Example

http://jsbin.com/hajokofavu/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

As there's not all that much code here to review, I've reviewed some style points:

You have some strange use of whitespace throughout your code:

> ```
> handleOnClick(key, event) {
>
>     event.preventDefault();
>
>     this.setState({
>         activeIndex : key
>                 // ^-- whitespace shouldn't be before a property colon
>     });
> }
> ```

and not necessarily that it's *wrong*, but there's a lot of empty whitespace lines that make your program look a lot beefier than it should.

> ```
> child.props.active === true ? true : (active == index++)
> ```

You don't need to compare properties to booleans as simply specifying the variable without comparison performs a boolean comparison:

```
var thing = true;
console.log(thing === true ? 1 : 2); // identical
console.log(thing ? 1 : 2);          // identical
```

You've also got some inconsistency in your use of semicolons:

> ```
> constructor() {
>
>     super();
>
>     this.state = {
>         activeIndex : 0
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the style advice. I'm not too well versed on the style guidelines for modern JavaScript, so it was quite helpful. Some of the whitespace I like to have for readability, it all gets compiled in the end so no need to worry about the code being beefy.

Answer (score 1):

Every thing looks good except one performance issue in the code. You have already `activeIndex`, so no need to traverse the whole map again to render tab content.

Here is the modified `Tabs` class as below:

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {

constructor() {

    super();

    this.state = {
        activeIndex : 0
    }
}

handleOnClick(key, event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        activeIndex : key
    });
}

renderNavItem(key) {

    let tab = this.props.children[key];

    return (
        <li key={ key } className={ this.state.activeIndex == key ? 'active' : ''}>
            <a href="#" onClick={ this.handleOnClick.bind(this, key) }>{ tab.props.title }</a>
        </li>
    );
}

render() {

    let active = this.state.activeIndex;

    let tabs = this.props.children[active];

    return (
        <div className={ this.props.className }>
            <ul className="tabs-nav">
                { Object.keys(this.props.children).map(this.renderNavItem.bind(this)) }
            </ul>
            <div className="tabs-content">
                { tabs.props.children }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
 }
```